# How to get a file from specific folder of device file manager without opening file manager in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I want to encrypt a video immediately after downloading it. My video stores on the location: /storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/0/All ExamBd/FIlename-1.mp4 .

Now, How can I get this file from the specific folder of the device file manager without opening the file manager in android studio? can anyone tell how to refresh this specific folder also?

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/storage/emulated/0/All ExamBd/FIlename-1.mp4 .`. That is not a normal path. Do you mean: `/storage/emulated/0/All ExamBd/FIlename-1.mp4 .`?

Comment: Of course you can directly open the file. But you did not tell what you wanna do with the file or what should be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use CipherOutputStream and CipherInputStream for encryption and decryption of file in android.

There are two ways through which you can achieve your goal

Download a file and encrypt it, when you want to play that file decry-pt it in a temporary file and play it.

if you want to play encrypted file on the fly (not decrypting it in a temp file) then you can use Libmedia library. It streams encrypted file on local host and play it from there